# compiling gcc - cannot find output from flex; giving up

Tags: gcc, flex-lexer, configure

I am trying to compile `gcc-4.9RC` or `gcc-4.8.2` on Debian (6 or 7).

There is `flex 2.5.35` installed and I even compiled my own flex `2.5.39`.

I confirmed it generates a `yy.c` output from a simple `.l` file.

Also I learned at gcc documentation, that flex shouldn't be necessary when compiling from a release (which the gcc-4.8.2 is).

Nevertheless I always get this in some internal `configure` after running `make`:

```
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... configure: error: cannot find output from flex; giving up
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-gmp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `***/gcc-bin-8'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `***/gcc-bin-8'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It is configured with:

```
../gcc-4.8.2/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --with-cloog --prefix=/home/***/gcc-4.8.2
```

I have no idea what should I try more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is generated whilst building gmp (a pre-requisite of gcc). It's a known bug in gmp present in 4.8.3 [Ref :gmp bug](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-bugs/2008-August/001114.html). If you ran contrib/download_prerequisites, you would get gmp 4.8.3 by default. Workaround is to edit gmp-4.8.3/configure.in & gmp-4.8.3/configure and change

`M4=m4-not-required`

for

`M4=m4`

Comment: Since the current version of GMP is 6.0.0a, I'm left wondering why the OP would use such an archaic version of GMP.  I built GCC 4.9.1 happily on Mac OS X 10.9.4 and an Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr derivative using GMP 6.0.0a (and MPC 1.0.2, MPFR 3.1.2, and ISL 0.12.2 and Cloog 0.18.1), which I had GCC build as it was building everything else.

Comment: OP doesn't say which version of GMP he is using

Comment: There was apparently a mess in the libraries, as I had some in my home directory (new) and some (the old ones) in the main system. I still did not succeed in compiling new GCC there, but I now use the Intel compilers instead until the admins build something recent for me. BTW, I compile GCC from source very often on my own computers and I never have such problems.